# MySQL MATCH() AGAINST()

Tags: mysql, sql, match-against

I want to find all records from database where `date` is "2013-04".

I use:

```
SELECT date, pastabos 
FROM aktai 
WHERE MATCH(uzsakovas) AGAINST ('Statyba ir Architektūra, UAB' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  AND MATCH(date) AGAINST ('2013-04*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

but it does not give the correct answer, because I get records with date equal to '`2013-01-29', '2013-03-28'`.

My question is how to use the `MATCH() AGAINST()` like function `LIKE()`  with `"2013-04%"` ?

Comment: @penfold type date is `date` '0000-00-00'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the data type of `date` is Date why are you using text search? Just search on the date:

```
SELECT date, pastabos 
FROM aktai 
WHERE MATCH(uzsakovas) AGAINST ('Statyba ir Architektūra, UAB' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  AND year(date) = :year and  month(date) = :month;
```

where :year and :month are integer parameters with values 2013 and 04 respectively.

Alternatively

```
SELECT date, pastabos 
FROM aktai 
WHERE MATCH(uzsakovas) AGAINST ('Statyba ir Architektūra, UAB' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  AND date between :date_from and :date_to;
```

where :date_from and :date_to are Date parameters with the values `2013-04-01` and `2013-04-30` respectively.

Comment: If the date field has a time component, using between could cause you to miss records.

Comment: @DanBracuk In the question the type was specified as `Date` which has no time component. If it was a `DateTime` or `TimeStamp` I agree that the second approach would not be appropriate unless the field was cast to a `Date` type.

Answer (score 1):

'-' has a special meaning in full text search syntax (word should be absent). Enclose the phrase in double quotes to match only rows that contain the phrase literally. I.e.:

```
match(date) against ('"2013-04"' in boolean mode)
```

And, generally, better approach would be to handle dates as the date type, not strings.

Comment: I have variable it's ok ? `MATCH(date) AGAINST ('".".$a_date."."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` ?

Answer (score 1):

`FULLTEXT` is not a precise operation, and it is expensive. Having 2 `FULLTEXT` searches in 1 query is always a bad idea. Use `LIKE` or date functions instead.

1)

```
WHERE `date` LIKE '2013-04-%'
```

2)

```
WHERE YEAR(`date`) = 2013 AND MONTH(`date`) = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using functions in the where clause of a query tends to slow down production, especially on indexed fields.  Also, if your date field includes a time component, as is often the case, then ignoring the time component could lead to incorrect results.

It's very hard to improve on this approach:

```
 where yourdatefield >= StartDate
 and yourdatefield < the day after EndDate
```

In your case, StartDate is 2013-04-01 and the day after EndDate is 2013-05-01.  Since you are using date parameters, it shouldn't be that difficult to get the day after EndDate.